# JavaScript WebAudio generate sound with multiple frequencies

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

Is there a way to create sound with multiple frequencies in JavaScript?

I can use WebAudio and create something with one frequency.

```
var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
osc.frequency.value = 440; //Some frequency
```

But I need to create a sound signal with many frequencies on it.
Is it possible?

Comment: Just create an other oscillator ? https://jsfiddle.net/puc4onau/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pang's answer wasn't bad - just add more oscillators, and connect() them all to the AudioContext.destination, and start() them all - but you can also use different types of oscillators.  The different waveforms (sawtooth, square, triangle) have different harmonic components - and in fact, you can use the PeriodicWave object and Oscillator.setPeriodicWave to select custom harmonic components.

Comment: I tried adding more oscillators, but for some reason when I `start` more than one oscillator the method creates a random noise with frequencies I don't want.

Comment: My bad, now I notice that I have to create a new instance from context too in order to works.

Comment: You shouldn't need another context; you probably need to feed them both through a gain node, set with gain <1, in order to avoid clipping.  Oscillators are full-signal (i.e max volume) by default.